# My ui object is all of sudden not existant anymore

Tags: c++, qt

I'm currently trying to get into QT, and created a project, along with doing some tinkering to set up my project structure, like, adding a model, controller and view.

However, after I did this, and tried to rebuild my project, I am suddenly facing this problem:

```
'TodoListerClass' is no element of 'Ui'
```

I did not change anything in my project despite adding some GUI elements, but thats about it.

The autogenerated UI object just doesn't seem to be there anymore, straightforward.

Any idea how to fix this? Note that I am using VS2013 with the QT addin.

EDIT:

After a few rebuilds, I now also get the error, that no resources are inside my .qrc file. Could that be related?

Comment: VS with QT can sometimes be a mess. Where does this error message appear exactly and when? I would try checking that all moc.cpp files are still added to the project. Also, I would check for the corresponding ui_... header to be included. If generation of some Q_OBJECT file does not work, you might try changing something irrelevant in the header file (adding a space or anything) and regeneration might be triggered

Comment: @IceFire I'm getting this error from IntelliSense as well as when trying to compile. I also added an edit to my OP, In case that helps

Comment: The compilation error would be a better thing to post in my opinion. Have you tried compiling the qrc file in isolation? If there really are no resources in there, you should also see this in the resource editor or in the text format of the file... you should find a hint that way!

Comment: @IceFire Found the problem. I accidently renamed my whole window in the GUI to a name which was meant for a single element, therefore my TodoListerClass was gone. Seems like I missclicked :)

Comment: If you're new to Qt, it's easier to start with Qt Creator + MinGW than VS (tutorials, example, template projects,...). Especially if you're using ui files.